# Adding custom text to a Word cross-reference field

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes, cross-reference

I've got a very long document that uses multi-level numbering. I'm wanting to include cross-references (with hyperlinks) back and forth to particular sections, and I've been using the standard Word cross-referencing feature, which adds fields like this:

```
{ REF _Ref391986184 \r \h }
```

This results in section references that look like this:

```
5.4
```

I'd really like the field to be formatted like this:

```
Section 5.4
```

and have the field automatically include the 'Section' part (so it ends up being a hyperlink as well).

I've been playing around with the REF field code's switches but I can't find anything that lets me format like this. The closest I've got is:

```
REF _Ref394485517 \r \h \# "'Section' 0.0"
```

At first glance this looks right as it outputs:

```
Section 5.4
```

However if the section being referred to has three parts (e.g. section 5.4.1), then this will only display the 5.4.

Is there another way to do this to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{ REF _Ref394485517 \r \h \#"'Section '" }{ REF _Ref394485517 \r \h }
```

If necessary, change the space after "Section" to a non-breaking space.

(NB, it can only work if the numbering contains at least one digit, e.g. a numbering style A.A.A would break this. AFAIK 1.2.3 etc. are OK even though they are not well-formed numbers as far as Word is concerned).

Comment: Thanks. This works! I was hoping to find a way of doing it in a single field so I could use Find and Replace to change this, but I'll just write a macro. Thanks.

Comment: Can you answer the question in the following link? Thank you. https://superuser.com/questions/1647346/the-set-field-codes-in-ms-word-doesnt-run-correctly