# Word 2013 custom text in cross-reference stopped working

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, field-codes, cross-reference

I noticed today that custom text in cross references in my document stopped working. When I started working on the doc I followed the answer in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/795217/adding-custom-text-to-a-word-cross-reference-field) so whenever I wanted a cross reference to a specified heading that said e.g. "Section 1" I did this:

{ REF _Ref123456 \r \h \#"'Section '"}{ REF _Ref123456 \r \h}

Today I opened the doc to make some changes and I noticed that when I update the fields the custom text disappears and I am left with just '11'. I get this behaviour in every other document I have on my hard drive and in all new documents.

So basically, what should I do to get it to work as it used to?

**Edit 1:**  So I've noticed that if I use \@ instead of # it kinda works. However, when I refer to any Heading 1 (so single digit) it doesn't replace the link with the word "Section" but stays with the number. It also kinda works when i use PAGEREF instead of REF. But the question still remains why it stopped working correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Changing REF to PAGEREF worked. Apparently, you can change reference to a page reference, but the link will still take you to its original position. The fields now look like so: { PAGEREF _Ref123456 \r \h #"'Section '"}{ REF _Ref123456 \r \h} the first one toggles back to just *Section*.