# Adding static text to a field

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I have added hyperlinked cross-references to my Word document, like this:

[image: MS Word cross-reference]

I would like the word 'Section' to also be hyperlinked. Manually adding a hyperlink isn't working because not all the headings I want to link to are in the list of places in the document.

So, I thought one solution would be to add the word Section to the cross-reference using field codes. I've tried writing "Section" in the field code but nothing happens. Does anyone know how to add static text to a field?

Comment: Sorry I can't embed the image as I don't have the reputation.

Comment: Blast now I see someone's already done this... http://superuser.com/questions/795217/adding-custom-text-to-a-word-cross-reference-field?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can add a switch to the REF field that is inserted, in your case it would be \d "Section ".  See screenshot below for example of the field (including the non-breaking space to keep the word Section with the number), as well as the resulting field.

[image: Adding text to cross-reference field]